# Yii2 ActiveForm custom template for checkbox field

Tags: templates, yii2, checkboxlist

I'm looking to use a template for my checkboxList.
That's the properties i want to apply

**class="switch" checked data-on-text="ON" data-off-text="OFF" data-on-color="teal"**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?> 
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li>
                                    <?= $form->field($modelUserPermission, 'id_permission')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map(Permission::find()->all(),'id', 'code')) ?>
                                </li><br>  
                           </ul>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?= Html::submitButton($modelUserPermission->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $modelUserPermission->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary', 'value'=>'Create', 'name'=>'submit']) ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: You want to apply these properties to each checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'recomended_by_user', ['template'=>'<div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control control--checkbox checkbox-small-text">Recomended by user
                                    {input}
                                    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>'])->textInput(['class'=>"",'type'=>'checkbox'])?>
```

Use like this for custom Checkbox template

Comment: Its only for single checkBox, Not for checkbox list

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by **Bizley** is correct, but here is one more alternate way you can try if you want.

```
<?php 
    $items_array = ArrayHelper::map(Permission::find()->all(),'id', 'code');

    echo $form->field($model, 'id_permission')->checkboxList($items_array, [
        'items' =>
        function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
            return Html::checkbox($name, $checked, [
                        'value' => $value,
                        'label' => '<label for="' . $label . '">' . $label . '</label>',
                        'labelOptions' => [
                        // you can set label options here                                                ],
                        ],
            ]);
        }, 'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'switch',
                    'data-on-text' => 'ON', 'data-off-text' => 'OFF', 'data-on-color' => 'teal'],
                'separator' => false,]);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want these properties in every checkbox (like Insane Skull asked) use `itemOptions` option.

```
<?= $form->field($modelUserPermission, 'id_permission')->checkboxList(
    ArrayHelper::map(Permission::find()->all(),'id', 'code'),
    [
        'itemOptions' => [
            'class' => 'switch',
            'data' => [
                'on-text' => 'ON',
                'off-text' => 'OFF',
                'on-color' => 'teal'
            ],
        ],
    ]
) ?>
```

Since it's ActiveField widget in order to get all checkboxes checked you have to pass array to `$modelUserPermission->id_permission` with all the IDs.

Comment: I already did it but it doesn't work i got always the default style

Comment: This depends on how and where you applied the style itself, the code above adds all the properties as you requested.